# I try to run an application in android studio with these parameters Nougat Android 7.1.1 armeabi-v7a, but the emulator is not generating an image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, avd-manager

I need to run a mobile virtual machine with specific parameters like: Nougat Android 7.1.1 armeabi-v7a But whenever I run the emulator nothing is displayed on the screen.
When I saw the emulator log, I noticed several errors, among which the most outstanding was SurfaceFlinger.

```
01-01 00:00:05.825   690   729 E vold    : Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
01-01 00:00:05.827   690   729 E vold    : Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
01-01 00:00:05.828   690   729 E vold    : Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
01-01 00:00:12.472   757   757 E perfprofd: unable to open configuration file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/perfprofd.conf
01-01 00:00:17.503   737   737 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:00:17.503   737   737 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
--------- beginning of crash                                                                            
01-01 00:00:17.508   737   737 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 737 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:00:18.483   792   792 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:00:18.523   792   792 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:00:18.524   792   792 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:00:18.524   792   792 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:00:18.526   792   792 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:00:18.529   792   792 F DEBUG   : pid: 737, tid: 737, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:00:18.672   792   792 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:00:18.673   792   792 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 000002e1  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:00:18.674   792   792 F DEBUG   :     r4 abde5584  r5 00000006  r6 abde552c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:00:18.674   792   792 F DEBUG   :     r8 ab7e94f4  r9 ab7e9398  sl 00000000  fp bec6bb9c
01-01 00:00:18.675   792   792 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bec6b9b0  lr ab9a641f  pc ab9a8c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:00:19.499   792   792 F DEBUG   :
01-01 00:00:19.499   792   792 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:00:19.500   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:00:19.501   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:00:19.501   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001c6fd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 00:00:19.632   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0001825f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-01 00:00:19.632   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 00:00:19.633   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00030aa3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:00:19.633   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00027589  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+312)
01-01 00:00:19.634   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000fdd  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:19.634   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016c4d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
01-01 00:00:19.635   792   792 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000e90  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:23.939   741   741 E EmulatedCamera_Factory: 0 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
01-01 00:00:24.044   741   741 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:00:24.045   741   741 E CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
01-01 00:00:27.555   689   689 E         : debuggerd: worker process 792 timed out
01-01 00:00:27.692   689   689 E         : debuggerd: killing target 737
01-01 00:00:27.775   740   740 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:00:27.776   740   740 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:00:33.366   824   824 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:00:33.368   824   824 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:00:33.380   824   824 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 824 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:00:33.393   689   689 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:00:33.447   689   689 E         : debuggerd: killing target 824
01-01 00:00:38.341   854   854 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:00:38.342   854   854 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:00:38.346   854   854 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 854 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:00:38.888   880   880 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:00:38.954   880   880 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:00:38.955   880   880 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:00:38.956   880   880 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:00:38.956   880   880 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:00:38.958   880   880 F DEBUG   : pid: 854, tid: 854, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:00:38.959   880   880 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:00:38.959   880   880 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000356  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:00:39.022   880   880 F DEBUG   :     r4 adba7584  r5 00000006  r6 adba752c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:00:39.023   880   880 F DEBUG   :     r8 ad5694f4  r9 ad569398  sl 00000000  fp be828b9c
01-01 00:00:39.023   880   880 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp be8289b0  lr ad91541f  pc ad917c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:00:39.561   880   880 F DEBUG   :
01-01 00:00:39.561   880   880 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:00:39.562   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:00:39.563   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:00:39.563   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001c6fd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 00:00:39.564   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0001825f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-01 00:00:39.564   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 00:00:39.564   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00030aa3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:00:39.565   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00027589  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+312)
01-01 00:00:39.565   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000fdd  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:39.566   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016c4d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
01-01 00:00:39.566   880   880 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000e90  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:00:43.064   861   861 E EmulatedCamera_Factory: 0 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
01-01 00:00:43.067   861   861 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:00:43.068   861   861 E CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
01-01 00:00:44.719   860   860 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:00:44.720   860   860 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:00:45.110   860   860 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
01-01 00:00:45.110   860   860 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
01-01 00:00:45.492   860   860 E RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:00:45.495   860   860 E SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:00:48.372   856   856 E         : debuggerd: worker process 880 timed out
01-01 00:00:48.482   856   856 E         : debuggerd: killing target 854
01-01 00:00:53.880   933   933 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:00:53.881   933   933 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:00:53.885   933   933 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 933 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:00:53.896   856   856 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:00:53.941   856   856 E         : debuggerd: killing target 933
01-01 00:00:59.669   961   961 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:00:59.670   961   961 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:00:59.693   961   961 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 961 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:00.237   994   994 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:00.293   994   994 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:01:00.294   994   994 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:01:00.295   994   994 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:01:00.295   994   994 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:01:00.296   994   994 F DEBUG   : pid: 961, tid: 961, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:01:00.297   994   994 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:01:00.297   994   994 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 000003c1  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:01:00.298   994   994 F DEBUG   :     r4 b589f584  r5 00000006  r6 b589f52c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:01:00.298   994   994 F DEBUG   :     r8 b52694f4  r9 b5269398  sl 00000000  fp bed90b9c
01-01 00:01:00.299   994   994 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bed909b0  lr b561641f  pc b5618c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:01:00.854   994   994 F DEBUG   :
01-01 00:01:00.854   994   994 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:01:00.855   994   994 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:01:00.856   994   994 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:01:06.732   964   964 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:01:06.732   964   964 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:01:07.086   964   964 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
01-01 00:01:07.086   964   964 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
01-01 00:01:07.176   964   964 E RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:07.194   964   964 E SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:09.743   962   962 E         : debuggerd: worker process 994 timed out
01-01 00:01:09.748   962   962 E         : debuggerd: killing target 961
01-01 00:01:14.747  1039  1039 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:01:14.748  1039  1039 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:01:14.754  1039  1039 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1039 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:14.793   962   962 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:01:14.913   962   962 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1039
01-01 00:01:20.942  1063  1063 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:01:20.942  1063  1063 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:01:20.946  1063  1063 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1063 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:21.753  1093  1093 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:21.805  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:01:21.807  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:01:21.807  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:01:21.808  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:01:21.809  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : pid: 1063, tid: 1063, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:01:21.810  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:01:21.912  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000427  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:01:21.912  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     r4 b4457584  r5 00000006  r6 b445752c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:01:21.913  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     r8 b3e694f4  r9 b3e69398  sl 00000000  fp be868b9c
01-01 00:01:21.914  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp be8689b0  lr b40a141f  pc b40a3c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:01:22.643  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : 
01-01 00:01:22.643  1093  1093 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:01:22.645  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:01:22.645  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:01:22.645  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001c6fd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 00:01:22.646  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0001825f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-01 00:01:22.646  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 00:01:22.646  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00030aa3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:01:22.647  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00027589  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+312)
01-01 00:01:22.647  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000fdd  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:01:22.647  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016c4d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
01-01 00:01:22.648  1093  1093 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000e90  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:01:26.153  1071  1071 E EmulatedCamera_Factory: 0 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
01-01 00:01:26.156  1071  1071 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:01:26.157  1071  1071 E CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
01-01 00:01:27.559  1105  1105 E hostapd : Configuration file: /system/etc/simulated_hostapd.conf
01-01 00:01:28.664  1078  1078 E ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
01-01 00:01:28.666  1078  1078 E ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to radio0-peer: Cannot assign requested address
01-01 00:01:29.491  1070  1070 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:01:29.492  1070  1070 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:01:29.745  1070  1070 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
01-01 00:01:29.745  1070  1070 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
01-01 00:01:29.803  1070  1070 E RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:29.814  1070  1070 E SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:30.992  1066  1066 E         : debuggerd: worker process 1093 timed out
01-01 00:01:30.995  1066  1066 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1063
01-01 00:01:32.648  1078  1078 E ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
01-01 00:01:34.711  1132  1132 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:01:34.712  1132  1132 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:01:34.715  1132  1132 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1132 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:34.720  1066  1066 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:01:34.741  1066  1066 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1132
01-01 00:01:34.926  1105  1105 E hostapd : Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00 and ssid "AndroidWifi"
01-01 00:01:40.925  1163  1163 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:01:40.927  1163  1163 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:01:40.942  1163  1163 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1163 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:41.344  1176  1176 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:41.365  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:01:41.367  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:01:41.368  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:01:41.368  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:01:41.370  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : pid: 1163, tid: 1163, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:01:41.430  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:01:41.431  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 0000048b  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:01:41.432  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     r4 b5806584  r5 00000006  r6 b580652c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:01:41.432  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     r8 b51e94f4  r9 b51e9398  sl 00000000  fp beddbb9c
01-01 00:01:41.433  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp beddb9b0  lr b541641f  pc b5418c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:01:41.788  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :
01-01 00:01:41.788  1176  1176 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:01:41.789  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:01:41.789  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:01:41.790  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001c6fd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 00:01:41.870  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0001825f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-01 00:01:41.871  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 00:01:41.871  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00030aa3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:01:41.872  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00027589  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+312)
01-01 00:01:41.872  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000fdd  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:01:41.872  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016c4d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
01-01 00:01:41.873  1176  1176 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000e90  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:01:43.715  1160  1160 E EmulatedCamera_Factory: 0 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
01-01 00:01:43.718  1160  1160 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:01:43.719  1160  1160 E CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
01-01 00:01:45.080  1159  1159 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:01:45.122  1159  1159 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:01:45.311  1159  1159 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
01-01 00:01:45.312  1159  1159 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
01-01 00:01:45.342  1159  1159 E RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:45.363  1159  1159 E SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:50.981  1154  1154 E         : debuggerd: worker process 1176 timed out
01-01 00:01:51.038  1154  1154 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1163
01-01 00:01:54.745  1220  1220 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:01:54.745  1220  1220 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:01:54.748  1220  1220 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1220 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:01:54.756  1154  1154 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:01:54.763  1154  1154 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1220
01-01 00:02:00.291  1248  1248 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:02:00.291  1248  1248 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:02:00.294  1248  1248 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1248 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:02:00.610  1261  1261 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:02:00.674  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:02:00.675  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_armv7/generic:7.1.1/NYC/6695155:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:02:00.676  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:02:00.676  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-01 00:02:00.677  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : pid: 1248, tid: 1248, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
01-01 00:02:00.678  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 00:02:00.679  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 000004e0  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-01 00:02:00.679  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     r4 ace02584  r5 00000006  r6 ace0252c  r7 0000010c
01-01 00:02:00.680  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     r8 ac7e94f4  r9 ac7e9398  sl 00000000  fp bec87b9c
01-01 00:02:00.680  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000002  sp bec879b0  lr acb9341f  pc acb95c6c  cpsr 20000010
01-01 00:02:01.235  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : 
01-01 00:02:01.235  1261  1261 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:02:01.238  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00048c6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 00:02:01.239  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004641b  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-01 00:02:01.239  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0001c6fd  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 00:02:01.239  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0001825f  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-01 00:02:01.240  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 00:02:01.291  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00030aa3  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
01-01 00:02:01.291  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00027589  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (_ZN7android14SurfaceFlinger4initEv+312)
01-01 00:02:01.292  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000fdd  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:02:01.292  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00016c4d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
01-01 00:02:01.292  1261  1261 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00000e90  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-01 00:02:03.355  1245  1245 E EmulatedCamera_Factory: 0 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
01-01 00:02:03.358  1245  1245 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:02:03.358  1245  1245 E CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
01-01 00:02:05.083  1244  1244 E AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't open audio hw device in audio.primary
 (Function not implemented)
01-01 00:02:05.084  1244  1244 E AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -38 loading module primary
01-01 00:02:05.283  1244  1244 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Default device 00000002 is unreachable
01-01 00:02:05.283  1244  1244 E APM_AudioPolicyManager: Failed to open primary output
01-01 00:02:05.339  1244  1244 E RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:02:05.353  1244  1244 E SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:02:10.301  1239  1239 E         : debuggerd: worker process 1261 timed out
01-01 00:02:10.308  1239  1239 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1248
01-01 00:02:14.472  1304  1304 E SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
01-01 00:02:14.473  1304  1304 E SurfaceFlinger: ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
01-01 00:02:14.477  1304  1304 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1304 (surfaceflinger)
01-01 00:02:14.483  1239  1239 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:02:14.521  1239  1239 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1304
```

I cannot run another ABI, i need execute in in this specific device.

I tried changing the parameters, but nothing is run.
That is the last a tried.

```
AVD NAME: Pixel API 25
5.0 1080x1920 420dpi
Nougat Android 7.1.1 armeabi-v7a
Camera:
Fontal: none
Back: none
Network:
Speed: HSDPA
Latency: EDGE
Emulated Performance
Graphics: Software - GLES 1.1
Boot option:
Quick Boot
Multi-Core CPU: 1
Memory and Storage:
RAM: 1024mb
VM heap: 512mb
Internal Storage: 2048mb
SD card:
Studio managed: 512mb
Custom Skin definition: No Skin
```

Comment: That emulator images for old Android versions don't run properly in recent version of Android emulator is unfortunately nothing unusual. I don't know why this happens and I am not sure if you can find a fix. The easiest work-around would be to buy a used phone running the same Android version for a few bucks on eBay or similar sites or ask your friends if they have such an old phone still laying around.